# why do I get an error 'invalid arithmetic operator'?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to parse yaml to Json.
and I'd like to set the array that has string index.

when I v tried it I got an error

here is my source and error

```
keys=$(echo $ci_json | jq 'keys')
key_array=($keys)
ARR=()

for raw_key in ${key_array[@]}; do
        if [ $raw_key = '[' -o $raw_key = ']' ]; then
                continue;
        else
                key=$(echo $raw_key | sed -e 's/"//g' -e 's/,//g')
                value=$(echo $ci_json | jq .$key)$'\t'
                ARR[$key]=$value
        fi
done
```

Error : localhost.localdomain: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".localdomain")

This error appeared at "ARR[$key]=$value"

anybody helps me?

This is ma key list :

APP_TYPE
APP_USE
ASSETS_NO
ASSETS_STAT
ASSETS_TYPE
BIZ_GROUP
BIZ_L1
BIZ_L2
CI_COMMENT
CI_NO
CI_OWNER
CI_PARENT
CPU_CLOCK
CPU_CORE
CPU_MODEL
CPU_NUM
CPU_VENDOR
DB_ADMIN1
DB_ADMIN2
DEV_ADMIN
DEV_ADMIN2
DISUSE_DATE
ENTER_DATE
EXPIRE_DATE
HDD_MODEL
HDD_NUM
HDD_TYPE
HDD_VENDOR
HDD_VOL
HOLE_NO
HOSTNAME
IDC
INTO_DATE
MAINT_CORP
MAINT_DATE
MEM_MODEL
MEM_NUM
MEM_VENDOR
MEM_VOL
MODEL
NIC1_IP
NIC1_MAC
NIC1_PORT
NIC1_SW
NIC2_IP
NIC2_MAC
NIC2_PORT
NIC2_SW
NIC_MODEL
NIC_VENDOR
OOB_IP
OOB_MAC
OOB_PORT
OOB_SW
OS_ARCH
OS_KERNEL
OS_NAME
RACK
RACK_NO
RAID_CACHE
RAID_FIRM
RAID_MODEL
RAID_NO
RAID_VENDOR
REPRESENT
SC_ADMIN
SC_CATEGORY
SC_DEPT
SC_TYPE
SEND_DATE
SERIAL_NO
SERVER_CLASS
SIM
SPEC_CODE
SVC_GROUP
SVC_L1
SVC_L2
SYS_ADMIN
SYS_ADMIN2
UNIT
USE_DESC
VENDOR
VM_CLASS
VM_TYPE
assignType

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You mention parsing YAML to generate equivalent JSON, but you are using `jq` to parse the input. What does your input look like, and what is the expected output? The less `bash` actually touches any of the data, the more likely it is your code won't break on valid input.

Comment: What I am trying to do is sending a protocol and getting YAML data then change YAML to JSON cuz I think JSON is easier than YAML to parse. that's why I am using jq. I could change YAML to JSON and I wanna set array which has string indices and has data from JSON. I'd like to expect I can set array like "ARR[$key]=$value" but when I try it, an error occur. sorry for ma bad english..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>  Error : localhost.localdomain: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".localdomain")
> ```

This happens on `ARR[$key]=...` when `ARR` is an indexed array (not associative) and the value of `key` is `localhost.localdomain`.
Indexed arrays should use numeric subscripts, not arbitrary strings.

If you want to use string indexes with `ARR`,
you must declare it as an associative array,
which is supported as of Bash 4:

```
declare -A ARR
```

Comment: but there is no key like localhost.localdomain! that's what drives me crazy

Comment: Your computer disagrees with you. Add an `echo $key` statement before the `ARR[$key]=...` line. You will see that you do have such key, probably due to another error you (evidently) didn't expect.

Comment: what if I can't find any key even similar one, what can i try for it

Comment: I don't understand your question. From the error message it is evident that you have such key. Look at the output of `echo $ci_json | jq 'keys' | grep localhost`. Not sure what more help you need.

Comment: I'll try it more , THX ANYWAY

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use non-numeric keys, use an associative array instead of a normal array. You have to declare it, though, so replace

```
ARR=()
```

with

```
declare -A ARR
```